# Fetch error in application with nextjs, apache

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I need help. When you deploy an application in nextjs on a centos9 server with apache (reverse proxy for pm2)
There is an error that I cannot make the fetch request. The funny thing is that the API is working and opening normally, I tested it in another application and it works too, but it doesn't work in this one.

Does anyone know what it could be?

```
const getAnuncios = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${Base_URL}/anuncio`);
    const data = await response.json();
    
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(Base_URL);
    console.log('getanuncios', error);
  }
}
```

Error:
[image: error]